# How to get the device token in react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios

I am using react-native 0.49.3 version, My Question is how to get the device token in react native for both IOS and Android I tried with this [link](https://medium.com/@DannyvanderJagt/how-to-use-push-notifications-in-react-native-41e8b14aadae) but it not working for me, right now I tried in IOS. how to resolve it can one tell me how to configure?

Comment: use this link to get device id https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

Comment: hi @KapilYadav what u shared the link only works for device Id, not for device token

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried different solutions and I've decided to use [React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase).

[Here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.*/messaging/reference/messaging) you will find everything about Notifications.

Also, you can use the others libraries that come with Firebase, like Analytics and Crash Reporting

After set up the library you can do something like:

```
// utils/firebase.js
import RNFirebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const configurationOptions = {
  debug: true,
  promptOnMissingPlayServices: true
}

const firebase = RNFirebase.initializeApp(configurationOptions)

export default firebase


// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

// I am using Device info
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

import firebase  from './utils/firebase';

class App extends Component {

 componentDidMount = () => {
    var language = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale();

    firebase.messaging().getToken().then((token) => {
       this._onChangeToken(token, language)
    });

    firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh((token) => {
        this._onChangeToken(token, language)
    });
  }

  _onChangeToken = (token, language) => {
    var data = {
      'device_token': token,
      'device_type': Platform.OS,
      'device_language': language
    };

    this._loadDeviceInfo(data).done();
  }

  _loadDeviceInfo = async (deviceData) => {
    // load the data in 'local storage'.
    // this value will be used by login and register components.
    var value = JSON.stringify(deviceData);
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(config.DEVICE_STORAGE_KEY, value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };  

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can call the server with the token and all the info that you need.

Comment: thank you for reply @Marcos Schroh I fixed the problem

Comment: i am going through same situation but i am using react-native-fcm for firebase push notification. is there any way to get device token from react-native-fcm package?

Comment: You can take a look  [here](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/blob/master/Examples/simple-fcm-client/app/App.js)  This is an example how to do it ( FCM.getFCMToken())

Comment: This method gets the FCM device token, but not the APNs token. The APNs token is useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: token is null in firebase.messaging.getToken().then() method only on IOS works  on android! someone tell me what is the problem..